# Can I get Darktable to change the order modules are displayed?

Tags: darktable

When I do some photo editing, I always have the same workflow:

1. Crop & rotate
2. Adjust white balance
3. Adjust brightness/contrast
4. Fine details

I'd like to have module displayed in that order in darktable, is this possible? Can I edit the module order? I tried with favorites also but it doesn't work. For some reason it takes an undetermined order each time:

[image: module order]

Answer (score 5):

No, currently the displayed order is, moving upward, the processing order. This processing order is used regardless of your workflow. From [the manual](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s02.html.php):

> Users frequently ask why the module order is fixed and if there are plans to change that restriction. There are several reasons why darktable works in the way described:
>
> - The sequence of modules has been selected with great care in order go give highest output quality. Changes to the sequence would generally worsen the result rather than improving it.
> - Certain image processing steps just don't make sense if they are shifted in the pixelpipe. To mention just a few: highlight reconstruction needs to be done on raw data before demosaicing and the demosaic step needs to be performed before any input color profile can be applied.
> - Most of darktable's modules are designed to work within a specific color model (see Section 3.2.10, “Color management” for more details). Full flexibility would require modules to support different parallel algorithms depending on the color space they are working in – this would drastically increase complexity.
>
> That said, the fixed sequence of modules is not likely to change in the near future.

UPDATE for 2.6: As of version 2.6, there is now some ability to customize the tab contents, as described [here](https://www.darktable.org/2018/12/darktable-26/). It requires editing of the darktable.css stylesheet, which may not be the most intuitive approach, but it's a start.

UPDATE for 3.0: It's now possible to change the ordering of the modules *for processing purposes*. This should *not* be used to make the GUI more convenient, since doing so will break the processing order.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you are talking about the order into which operations are applied on the picture. I don't have any issue with this. What I'm asking only concerns the display : crop and rotate at the top, then white balance etc. Couldn't this be user-customizable?

Comment: It quite possibly *could* be, but currently it isn't. All views show modules in processing order, from bottom to top. Making the ordering customizable in the "favorites" view might seem like a reasonable request, but apparently [the devs feel differently](https://redmine.darktable.org/issues/10435).